# How to select an UNTAG element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this here and like to see how to select the untagged element/text. I want to select the text "j.smith" in the following example:

```
<td class='dev'>
  <u>assigned</u>
  j.smith
</td>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the text always appears after <u> (underline ) tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in css you can't do this. 
for styling you can use jquery for finding that
like this:

```
$("td.dev").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 3; }).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the "j.smith" text isn't an element, it's just a text node which belongs to its parent `<td>`.

There are some proposals in CSS4 that might allow for similar behaviour to what you're looking for, but until then the workaround is to undo the changes to any child elements, like so:

```
td.dev { font-weight: bold; }
td > * { font-weight: normal; } /* this undoes the change to any children of the `<td>` */
```

Comment: I was thinking you could use the Reference Combinator to limit the scope of the style changes.

Comment: The reference combinator simply lets you select an element based on the IDREF of another element, for example an `input` whose ID is referenced by a `label for="..."` attribute. It doesn't select text nodes - there is no way to do so with CSS selectors.